# How to get sytem information using ILO using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My objective is to login to hp ilo and then get "system information" information in ILO.

> So far I am able to login to ILO , but I am unable to parse the system information correctly. 
>   Error I am getting is this .
>
> > "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> >     {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/ul/li[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQbkmxjy4XEvYTOB2vUasUDqyqnW30Zz/view)/ul/li[2]/a"}
> >     (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)"

My code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/for_ilden/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://10.63.10.4/")
print (driver.title)
print (driver.current_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='details-button']").click()
print (driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proceed-link']").click()
time.sleep(3)
print (driver.title)
#user_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='usernameInput']")
#driver.find_element_by_id("usernameInput").click()
driver.set_window_size(1280, 680)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
user_name=driver.find_element_by_id('usernameInput')
#pass_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='passwordInput']")
pass_name=driver.find_element_by_id('passwordInput')
user_name.send_keys("Admin")
pass_name.send_keys("shrogjd")
driver.find_element_by_id("ID_LOGON").click()
print (driver.title)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
print (driver.title)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

The system information link looks like this
[System_info link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQbkmxjy4XEvYTOB2vUasUDqyqnW30Zz/view)

The information I need is this

[Info_which_is_needed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQbkmxjy4XEvYTOB2vUasUDqyqnW30Zz/view)

Note: I know this can be done using hp_ilo packages. But for some reason its not working in my server.

Comment: can you confirm `/html/body/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a` is this displays in any iframe or simply  on html page ?

Comment: There's an API for iLO that would likely be easier to use than scraping HTML

Comment: @NarendraR:  From inspect layout I am not sure of this.So in my code , I have attached the full page source. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ql9RRGXan-bRtqjqR28r1KKc1rlD6u-N

Comment: @user1107731,  not possible to identify using the source you shared. Copy the relevant element HTML code from the page and update your question.

Comment: Seems like you are not identifying right frame. if there is no frame after login then use this code `driver.switch_to.default_content()` before `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()` this line

Comment: @NarendraR: It was resolved by adding these 2 statements.  driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame(1)